# Training with default BN parameters

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, batch-normalization

Training with default BN parameters in tensorflow I obtain strange loss curve.
For experiment train and val are the same dataset.

Blue is val loss, orange is train loss.

BN with momentum 0.99 (default) - strange loss curve.
[image]

BN with momentum 0.6 - works fine.
[image]

In train phase result is ok, in val it have some problems at start, so looks like the problem is the BN.

What can be a reason of such behaviour? Maybe it depends on optimizer?
How it's common to not use default BN parameters?

Answer (score 1):

With a decay of 0.01 / a momentum of 0.99, it takes several hundred iterations for the moving averages of the batch statistics to get burned in. This is easy to see because $(1-0.01)^{100} \approx 1/e$. Note that this is several hundred iterations AFTER training has converged and the batch statistics stop wildly moving around. Therefore using batch norm in test mode before this is premature and will result in strange outputs. Usually batch norm is operated in train mode for validation during training.

While setting the decay to a large value solves this, it will produce suboptimal results since you never end up with a good estimate of the mean batch statistics. I would not try to use anything under 0.99 momentum.

Comment: Is `decay=1.0-momentum` ?

Comment: @mrgloom yes it is

Comment: Looks like in practice lower momentum is still used, momentum=0.8 in this case of GAN https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/gan/gan.py#L58